# required hardware upgrade for old system

Tags: upgrade, hardware, system-requirements

I want to use Ubuntu 14.04.I do not wish to opt for lightweight versions so I need help in determining some reasonable hardware upgrades so I can use Ubuntu comfortably. Currently my system specs are as follows:
1)512mb of ram. Can be increased not more than 2 GB (would that be enough?)
2)No graphics card (would it be required?)
3)Processor is pentium 4
4)Speed is 2ghz.

Comment: It should run Ubuntu 14 fine right now. But I REALLY recommend that you increase your RAM. 2GB is enough but you did not state what kind of RAM it is. DDR3? DDR2?

Comment: it will run but it will be slow

Answer (score 1):

I've done this task before starting with a Pentium 4 computer that had 512MB RAM and no graphics card. I don't believe that a Pentium 4 computer can run Ubuntu 14.04 satisfactorily, so I downloaded Xubuntu 14.04 32-bit. I also added another 512MB of RAM. I could have used two 1GB RAM sticks instead, but I added only one 512MB RAM stick because it was what I had available at the time.

I installed Xubuntu and a few more apps, and when I tested the installation the performance was OK, including Firefox, so this is what I am recommending.

Compare prices before you buy RAM. You may find that adding to the RAM you already have is much cheaper than buying a new set of RAM sticks. Take an old RAM stick with you when you go to buy the RAM, so you can be sure that you are getting the type of RAM that is compatible with your motherboard.